# Pandas: Wide to Long after multiindex on columns is lost

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the usual `trades` dataframe:

```
trades = pd.DataFrame({
         'time': pd.to_datetime(['20160525 13:30:00.023',
                      '20160525 13:30:00.038',
                      '20160525 13:30:00.048',
                      '20160525 13:30:00.048',
                      '20160525 13:30:00.048']),
         'ticker': ['MSFT', 'MSFT','GOOG', 'BOOB', 'AAPL'],
         'price': [51.95, 51.95, 720.77, 720.92, 98.00],
         'quantity': [75, 155, 100, 100, 100]},
        columns=['time', 'ticker', 'price', 'quantity'])

trades
Out[42]: 
                     time ticker   price  quantity
0 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT   51.95        75
1 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT   51.95       155
2 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.77       100
3 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   BOOB  720.92       100
4 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL   98.00       100
```

**Here I want to reshape from long to wide, do some stuff, and then reshape back from wide to long**.

From long to wide is easy

```
trades.set_index(['time','ticker'], inplace = True)
trades = trades.unstack()

trades
Out[44]: 
                        price                        quantity                \
ticker                   AAPL    BOOB    GOOG   MSFT     AAPL   BOOB   GOOG   
time                                                                          
2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   NaN     NaN     NaN  51.95      NaN    NaN    NaN   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   NaN     NaN     NaN  51.95      NaN    NaN    NaN   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.048  98.0  720.92  720.77    NaN    100.0  100.0  100.0   


ticker                    MSFT  
time                            
2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   75.0  
2016-05-25 13:30:00.038  155.0  
2016-05-25 13:30:00.048    NaN
```

But now for many reasons, I do now want to work with this multiindex on the columns, so I have the following code:

```
trades.columns=['_'.join(t) for t in trades.columns]
```

That basically gets rid of the multiindex and allows me to work with normal columns. The data now looks like:

```
trades
Out[47]: 
                         price_AAPL  price_BOOB  price_GOOG  price_MSFT  \
time                                                                      
2016-05-25 13:30:00.023         NaN         NaN         NaN       51.95   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.038         NaN         NaN         NaN       51.95   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.048        98.0      720.92      720.77         NaN   

                         quantity_AAPL  quantity_BOOB  quantity_GOOG  \
time                                                                   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.023            NaN            NaN            NaN   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.038            NaN            NaN            NaN   
2016-05-25 13:30:00.048          100.0          100.0          100.0   

                         quantity_MSFT  
time                                    
2016-05-25 13:30:00.023           75.0  
2016-05-25 13:30:00.038          155.0  
2016-05-25 13:30:00.048            NaN
```

Problem is: how can I get back to a long format now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#create MultiIndex from columns 
trades.columns = trades.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
#stack and set index names for new column names
trades = trades.stack().rename_axis(['time','ticker']).reset_index()
#convert to int
trades.quantity = trades.quantity.astype(int)
print (trades)
                     time ticker   price  quantity
0 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT   51.95        75
1 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT   51.95       155
2 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL   98.00       100
3 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   BOOB  720.92       100
4 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.77       100
```

Comment: Magic! I guess the key here is the `expand = True` argument?

Comment: Yes, then is created `MultiIndex`

Comment: It was implemented in [pandas 0.16.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#string-methods-enhancements) - `In [38]:`

Comment: nice, can I ask you just a quick follow up? It appears some of the columns looks like `col_quantity_jezrael` where `jezrael` is the stock and `col_quantity` corresponds to the `quantity` above. Is there a way to have the `split` work correctly here (that is separating the column into `col_quantity` and `jezrael`)?

Comment: Then need `trades.columns = trades.columns.str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1)`